# ADO.Net Entity Data Model (mapping with Stored Procedure) and WCF in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

Here I have database:

**Tables**: `Product`, `Category` (one to one relationship)

**View**: `viewProduct` (view Product with Category relation)

**Stored Proc**:

`spProductSelect` (reading from `viewProduct`, with `pageSize`, `pageInde` input, and `RowCount` output)

spProductInsert, spProductUpdate, spProductDelete (data manipulation to Product table)

Requirement:

To create `webservice`, using `WCF`, which has CRUD function for Product.

Database operations must using Stored Procedure, not directly to the table/view.

For Reading/Select, `WCF` must return composite type, because not only `viewProduct` list, but also need to return `RowCount`.

- I've created `Entity Model (.edmx).` Drag and drop tables as Entity on diagram.
- Mapped Product entity to `viewProduct`
- Mapped Functions `insert`, `update`, `delete` to stored procedure respectively.

Questions:

1) How to create web method in `WCF` return value from `spProductSelect` as `viewProduct` list plus `RowCount`?

2) How to implement web method for `insert`, `update` and `delete`, since already mapped with Entity Type?

Comment: this seems like a task best tackled with Web API. You could use your Entity Model to scaffold API Controllers that will create the skeleton or rudimentary CRUDs.

Comment: Thanks I found solution already. I just import all tables, views, stored proc into the model.

I just knew that stored proc can be imported into the model and map to entity set/view. But there is inflexibility if require no mapping to certain column, so need to trick on this.

Overall quite nice, without sqlClient helper like dataSet old model, we can establish CRUDs easily.